# Images of derived categories of $X, Z$ in derived category of blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $Z \subset X$ be a locally complete intersection (smooth if needed). So $X, Z$ is as good as we need (i am working with toric varieties). Let $\pi : \mathrm{Bl}_Z X \to X$ be the blow up in $Z$ and $p: \tilde{Z} \to Z$ be the exceptional divisor and $j: \tilde Z\to \mathrm{Bl}_Z X$,  $ i : Z\to X$.

> Is it true that $j_*p^*\mathcal{D}^b(Z) \subset
> \pi^*\mathcal{D}^b(X)$?

Comment: Why is a complete intersection smooth?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez edited

Comment: Also, $\pi$ is $p$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez edited again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not true. In fact, these two subcategories are semiorthogonal: for any $F \in D^b(X)$, $G \in D^b(Z)$ one has
$$
Hom(j_*p^*G, \pi^*F) = 0.
$$
This is a part of Orlov's blowup Theorem (which is stated for smooth $Z$ in smooth $X$, but works as well for lci $Z$ in any $X$).

EDIT.
Actually, there are two semiorthogonal decompositions. One looks
$$
D^b(Bl_Z(X)) = \langle j_*(p^*D^b(Z) \otimes O(1-c)), \dots, 
j_*(p^*D^b(Z) \otimes O(-1)), \pi^*D^b(X) \rangle,
$$
while the other looks 
$$
D^b(Bl_Z(X)) = \langle \pi^*D^b(X), j_*(p^*D^b(Z)), \dots, 
j_*(p^*D^b(Z) \otimes O(c-2)) \rangle.
$$
I am using semiorthogonality of the second. In fact, it can be deduced from the semiorthogonality of the first by Serre duality.

Comment: Orlov states that $j_*(p^*\mathcal{D}^b(Z)\otimes \mathcal{O}(-k))$ is semiorthogonal to $\pi^*\mathcal{D}^b(X)$ for $k$ from $1$ to $\mathrm{codim}_X Z - 1$.
I don't sure that statement in my question is true but Orlov don't state semiorthogonality of that categories.

Comment: There are two semiorthogonal decompositions, I edited my answer to explain.